# ImageMagick - Monochromatic Noise

Tags: mono, imagemagick, noise

I'm trying to add a monochromatic noise to an image similar to Photoshop version using command line however I can't see any option to achieve it.

I've created a code in JS that does it very well and the logic here is very simple:

Foreach pixel:

1. Generate random noise pixel
2. Add or subtract (random) noise pixel to/from original pixel

The create a monochromatic noise add/subtract are on a pixel not channel basis e.g.

```
Pi - original pixel
Pr - noise pixel

MonoPixel = Pi+Pr or Pi-Pr
```

Is there any way I can randomly add or subtract pixels via command line ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you meant to file this under the "mono" tag.  You've got a monochromatic question.  Mono is a lib to code in .NET crossplaform.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ImageMagick [+noise command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#noise) to add noise.  To get monochromatic noise, you'll have to do something more complex where you create a separate noise image combined with a base color and composite that with your source image.

This link may be helpful: http://brunogirin.blogspot.com/2009/09/making-noise-with-imagemagick.html

Answer (score -1):

You could try and build your own little shell function. Use $RANDOM (Bash environment variable which returns a random integer in the range 0..32767) and see if it is an odd or an even number. Make odd to mean `+` and even to mean `-`.

```
 echo $(($RANDOM % 2))
```

should return `1` ($RANDOM was odd) or `0` ($RANDOM was even) in random order...